# Flow conditions executes TRUE, not FALSE

Tags: boolean, conditional-statements, sharepoint-online, power-automate

CONTEXT

- Created small ticket submission system for a personnel office. Created ability to submit ticket on behalf of another user, such as by a supervisor. Needed one column "CUSTOMER EMAIL" to fill with the email from the actual customer so the system would have one column by which to email the customer.

If SUBMITTED FOR is full, CUSTOMER EMAIL should have SUBMITTED FOR EMAIL.
If SUBMITTED FOR is empty, CUSTOMER EMAIL should have CREATED BY EMAIL.

FLOW

PART 1 (Works fine)

- TRIGGER: Update item/File
- CONDITION: TICKET ID column field is modified

FLOW PART 2 (Problem)

- CONDITION:

- "Has Column Changed: Submitted for"   IS EQUAL TO "Has Column Changed: Submitted for"
- Also Tried
- "Has Column Changed: Submitted for"   IS EQUAL TO fx: TRUE

Boolean:::

YES

- UPDATE ITEM:
  CUSTOMER EMAIL (col) with SUBMITTED FOR EMAIL (field)

NO

- UPDATE ITEM:
  CUSTOMER EMAIL (col) with CREATED BY EMAIL (field)

The FLOW TEST says it works, but when FALSE, doesn't execute the NO "UPDATE ITEM".

Please help!

[image: Test Results]

[image: Flow Layout]

[image: Still True]

Comment: Are the columns you're comparing in Condition 2 coming from different lists?

Comment: No ma'am. Same list.

Comment: Can you share the flow run screenshot for the False situation as well. Your first screenshot is for True condition where it is going inside Yes branch

Comment: Added the requested image. Or, rather, I can't get it to present as FALSE. Apparently, "Has Column Changed:" counts as TRUE regardless of whether anything is actually modified in the column. Is there a way to merely test if the column ISBLANK as my condition? I only want to activate TRUE/FALSE based on if "SUBMITTED FOR" has a value or not.

Comment: You could try "Submitted For" is equal to fx: null

Comment: @SarahCox Now using the "Submitted for" function. I think I've narrowed it down to problems with the CREATED BY field. No matter where I move the SUBMITTED FOR field (is equal to/YES) or (is not equal to/NO), it works. No matter where I put the CREATED BY, field, it refuses to copy the value (CREATED BY EMAIL) to the CUSTOMER field.

Comment: Scratch that. I don't really know what's happening and it's not a CREATED BY problem. Going to close out my question by posting that I apparently can't even accurately identify my own problem. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem:

In 2nd condition, was using "Has Column Changed:Submitted For" IS EQUAL TO fx:NULL.

But the value IS updated, even if the value is null, which produces a false positive.

Changed it to: "Submitted for" IS EQUAL TO fx:NULL.

My ignorance on difference between "Has changed" vs is the cell empty or not?